# Relative paths in open in Python 2.5 and 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.5

I have a script in python 2.5 that opens a file

```
f=open("./inputs/variable_list.csv","r")
```

It takes the path of the script thus goes to the folder to get the csv. However if I run the same line in Python 2.7 it doesn't know the path to open the file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\INRO\Emme\Emme4\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line    326, in RunScript
exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "X:\Daniel\training\model_runs\2010\iter0\write_model_setup_joan.py", line 6, in <module>
    f=open("./inputs/variable_list.csv","r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './inputs/variable_list.csv'
```

Why cant Python 2.7 handle the path as how 2.5 did? Also is there a way to make 2.7 handle the path as 2.5 did?

Comment: Why are you using *nix style paths on windows?

Comment: Is the current directory the same in both cases?

Comment: this is how the script was written, i did not write it

Comment: yeah same file script just using different versions of python

Comment: I'm betting they aren't being invoked (the pythons) from the same location, causing one to find the relative file and the other to not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script don't seems to be executed at the same place in both cases.

maybe ou should add at the beggining of the 2.7 script those lines:

```
import os
os.chdir('/location/of/your/script')
```

Comment: This worked but i still dont know the reason. Must have to do with the configuration of python